# Skipping the commas present in a fields when writing data to CSV file in java

Tags: java, csv

I am writing this data to a CSV file in Java. I am reading this from a text file and writing to CSV using `bufferedWriter`.

The data have 3 fields:

```
5,  [{"product":"xyz","company":"wipro","price":"20120"}],  India
```

This should result in a CSV file with 3 columns.

But I end up getting 5 fields:

```
5, 

[{"product":"xyz", 

 "company":"wipro", 

"price":"20120"}], 

India
```

Enclosing the middle field with double quote is not working here.

Comment: Could you please provide the code, where the file content is written.

Comment: CSV = comma separated values. It means column boundaries are on EVERY ',' -> that's why you end with 5 columns ... try to use TABs instead of comma as a separator

Answer (score 0):

since our data field consist of both double quotes(") and comma(,), simply enclosing the data field in double quotes ("field") would not work.

what worked for me is

1. first replace all the double quotes(") by two double quotes("").

   field.replace("\"", "\"\"")
2. Now enclose the field within double quote

   newField = " + field + "